# Beginner headaches: NullReferenceException from array on ASP.NET webfrom

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, nullreferenceexception

I have created a program for my ASP.NET class to create a class name and number and then enter in ten student names with student ID. So my web page will prompt the user to enter these 4 information pieces separating them into the **MyClass ( the course name and number)** and the **Student class ( where it holds the student name and ID)**. I am terribly stuck on the NullReferenceException error and don't know what to do. If anyone here could give me some pointers and direction so I can pick myself up from this assignment. One thing is certain, I am **not allowed** to enter any new methods and variables. I am only able to use the current ones I have initialized.

- The Student[] array is the array that holds my Student class with the name and id of students.
- The user first will create the class number and name in which to add students(with id and name) to it afterwards.
- Only 1 class name and number(they go together) is allowed and only 10 students is the maximum.

***I am getting the null exception on my ToString() method in MyClass where classNumberAndName += ((Student)students[i]).ToString();***

Here's my code with no syntax errors.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string courseNumber;
    private string courseName;
    private int numberOfStudents;
    private Student[] students;       
    public MyClass(string CourseNumber , string CourseName, Student[] Student)
    {
        students = new Student[Student.Length];
        courseNumber = CourseNumber;
        courseName = CourseName;
        for (int i = 0; i < Student.Length; i++)
        {
            Student tmpArrayStudent = new Student(((Student)students[i]).ToString(),((Student)students[i]).ToString());
            tmpArrayStudent = students[i];
        }
    }   
    public MyClass(string CourseNumber, string CourseName)
    {
        courseNumber = CourseNumber;
        courseName = CourseName;
        students = new Student[10];
    }
    public void addAStudent(Student student)
    {//possible to create temp array?
        Student[] students = new Student[10];
        if(numberOfStudents < students.Length)
        {
            students[numberOfStudents] = student;
            numberOfStudents++;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Amount of Students Exceeded, no more than 10");
        }
    }
    public string getClassNumberAndName()
    {
        return "Course Number: " + courseNumber + "   " + " Course Name: " + courseName;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string classNumberAndName = getClassNumberAndName();
        for(int i = 0; i < students.Length; i++)
        {
            classNumberAndName += ((Student)students[i]).ToString();
        }
        classNumberAndName += "Students Registered: " + numberOfStudents.ToString();
        return classNumberAndName;
    }
}


public class Student
{
    private string idNumber;
    private string name;
    public Student(string ID, string Name)
    {
        idNumber = ID;
        name = Name;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Student ID: " + idNumber + " " + " Student Name " + name;
    }       
}
```

And here is the .aspx.cs file for the web code.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            pnlStudent.Visible = false;//use panels to disable the ability to enter new course information
        }
    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyClass course = new MyClass(txtCnum.Text, txtCname.Text);
        Session.Add("Course", course);
        ((MyClass)Session["Course"]).addAStudent(new Student(txtCnum.Text, txtCname.Text));//since we entered to Student, course information or student information?

        txtAnswers.Text += course.ToString();

        pnlStudent.Visible = true;
    }
    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Student student = new Student(txtID.Text, txtName.Text);
        pnlCourse.Visible = false;
        try
        {
            ((MyClass)Session["Course"]).addAStudent(new Student(txtID.Text, txtName.Text));
            txtAnswers.Text += Session["Course"].ToString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            txtAnswers.Text += "Amount of students are at maximum." + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make it clear where you are getting the exception (and preferably make sample much smaller 5-7lines is usually enough). Also "thank you notes" are not needed as they add no information to the question(upvote/comment/accept instead).

Comment: Ok, I just added the "I am getting the null exception on my ToString() method in MyClass where classNumberAndName += ((Student)students[i]).ToString();"  I'm guessing all you need to see is the MyClass and the aspx.cs file. I was afraid I did not construct the array correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < students.Length; i++)
{
    classNumberAndName += ((Student)students[i]).ToString();
}
```

You are initialising students with `students = new Student[10]` so `students.Length` will be `10` even if you have inserted less than `10` students. The values you haven't filled in are `null`, so you end up doing `null.ToString`, hence the `NullReferenceException`.

I believe you should be using `numberOfStudents` instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++)
{
    classNumberAndName += ((Student)students[i]).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MyClass.ToString() method you should check the array if it is null, if yes then break the loop

here the code

```
public override string ToString()
```

{
    string classNumberAndName = getClassNumberAndName();

```
for (int i = 0; i < students.Length; i++)
{
    if (students[i] == null) break;
    classNumberAndName += ((Student)students[i]).ToString();
}
classNumberAndName += "Students Registered: " + numberOfStudents.ToString();
return classNumberAndName;
```

}

NOTE: you must delete the Student[] students = new Student[10] in addAStudent method

thanks

Comment: The NullReferenceException is from my ToString() method in MyClass where classNumberAndName += ((Student)students[i]).ToString();  I have also tried to remove the the Student[] students from addAStudent, then limited my private Student[] students = new Student[10]. I still get NullReferenceException

Answer (score 0):

You might need an empty constructor for your Student class that initializes the ID and Name to a default (empty) value.  something like public Student(){ID=-1;Name=String.Empty}
OR 
you are not initializing the array - taken from Microsoft's site...

Initializing Arrays

....

Note   If you do not initialize an array at the time of declaration, the array members are automatically initialized to the default initial value for the array type. Also, if you declare the array as a field of a type, it will be set to the default value null when you instantiate the type.

Answer (score 0):

You have students list of constant length. And you enumerate through it, however I can't see that you fill all the items in the array, so there is your NullReferanceException.
That will help:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string classNumberAndName = getClassNumberAndName();
    for(int i = 0; i < students.Length; i++)
    {
        if (students[i] != null)
            classNumberAndName += ((Student)students[i]).ToString();
    }
    classNumberAndName += "Students Registered: " + numberOfStudents.ToString();
    return classNumberAndName;
}
```